# getting lat long in double data type in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with google map.It is working fine and i m getting the lat long on marker options.but i want to pass that lat long in the other activity.so i need to change it in double data type.Because i have to give forecast information for that perticular location.Plz help me.here is my code.

```
  package com.example.gpstracking;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MapActivity1 extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG_LAT = "LAT";
    private static final String TAG_LONG = "LONGITUDE";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_activity1);
        MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        final GoogleMap map = fm.getMap();
        // Setting a click event handler for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                // Creating a marker
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position for the marker
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker.
                // This will be displayed on taping the marker
                markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

                // Clears the previously touched position
                map.clear();

                // Animating to the touched position
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
                map.addMarker(markerOptions);
                double lat=latLng.latitude;
                double longitude=latLng.longitude;
                String LAT=String.valueOf(lat);
                String LONGITUDE=String.valueOf(longitude);
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LocationActivity.class);
                // Sending lat/long to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_LAT, LAT);
                in.putExtra(TAG_LONG, LONGITUDE);
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_activity1, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Have you tried things below ?

**Converting to string and passing to another `activity`**

```
String dataToSend=LatLng.toString();
```

**If you are passing `double` to another `activity` convert the string to double**

```
double dataToSend=Double.valueof(LatLng.toString());
```

---

### Finally

If you are sending primitive data types use `intents` to send data else use `parcelable` or `serializable`(for java objects) to pass data

*Assuming you are sending primitive data:*

```
Intent int=new Intent(this,newActivity.class)
int.putExtra("key",dataToSend);
StartActivity(int);
```

*Then retrieve the data in the `newActivity.class`*

Comment: Yup it is working..Thank you so much..but marker title is not appear.it will redirect to the next activity...can you plz tell me why this was happened?I have edited my code.

Comment: @ bhagyasri patel ..... Marker title appears when you tap on the marker ....... If you want the title always to be displayed try using `markerOptions.showInfoWindow();` ..... Try this !

Comment: @ bhagyasri patel ......... If you were able to resolve the problem .... mark the answer as accepted so that it is helpful for someone looking for a similar question !

Comment: actually i was trying..googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title(String title))
        .showInfoWindow();....but it is not working...it is just showing me marker..not lat long..

Comment: Convert to string and then pass the value to .title(your value)

Comment: Check this tutorial to get to know how to use maps: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Answer (score 0):

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

```
                //private String stadion;

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
                {
                    float lat = (float)location.getLatitude();
                    float lon = (float)location.getLongitude();

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(stadion)
                    .position(new LatLng(lat,lon)));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lon), 10)); 

                    for(int i = 0; i < alleStadien.getLength(); i++){
                        Node stadion = alleStadien.item(i);

                        String name = stadion.getAttributes()
                                .getNamedItem(name)
                                .getNodeValue();
                        String verein = stadion.getAttributes()
                                .getNamedItem(verein)
                                .getNodeValue();
                        lat = (float)Float.valueOf(stadion.getAttributes()
                                .getNamedItem(lt)// Fehler
                                .getNodeValue());
                        lon = (float)Float.valueOf(stadion.getAttributes()
                                .getNamedItem(lg)// Fehler
                                .getNodeValue());
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(name)
                        .snippet(verein)
                        .position(new LatLng(lat,lon)));
                    }
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {}


            };
                geolocation.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, locationListener);
            }

            catch(ParserConfigurationException e){}
            catch(SAXException e){}
            catch(IOException e){}

}
```